# Cannot use Vuex to fetch data for all components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-cli

I tried to fetch data in App.vue and then pass the value to this.store.data. Afterwards I can use this.store.data value for all other components. The problem is when I click in the link (router-link), the function inside the components run before fetching data in app. Is there anyway I can fix this? How to fetch the data and use for all other components?

Here is the code of store.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
      senator: [],
  },
  mutations: {},
  actions: {}
});
```

Here is the fetch data code in App.vue:

```
<script>
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
export default {
    components: {Header, Footer},
    data(){
        return {
            senatorA: [],
        }
    },
    created: function(){
        this.getData();
    },
    methods: {
        getData() {
            let pathSenate = 'senate';
            let url = '';
            let currentPage = window.location.href;
            if (currentPage.includes(pathSenate)) {
                url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1eja30';

            } else {
                url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/j83do';
            }
            fetch(url)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then((jsonData) => {
                    let data = jsonData;
                    this.senatorA = data.results[0].members;
                    this.senatorA.forEach(mem => {
                        mem.fullname = (mem.first_name + ' ' + mem.middle_name + ' ' + mem.last_name).replace(null, '');
                    });
                    this.$store.state.senator = this.senatorA;
                    console.log(this.$store.state.senator)
                });
        },
    }
}
```

Here is the code in component in order to get data from fetch function in App.vue:

```
<script>
import DataTable from './DataTable'
export default {
    name: "FilterData",
    components: {DataTable},
    data () {
        return {
            senatorF: this.$store.state.senator,
            checkarr: [],
            selectarr: '',
            statearr: [],
            searchName: '',
            tempt: [],
        }
    },
    created: function(){
        this.getStates();
    },
    computed: {
        displayParty() {
            if (this.checkarr.length == 0 && this.selectarr == '') {
                return this.searchData(this.senatorF);
            } else if (this.checkarr.length != 0 && this.selectarr == '') {
                this.tempt = this.senatorF.filter(j => this.checkarr.includes(j.party));
                return this.searchData(this.tempt);
            } else if (this.selectarr != '' && this.checkarr.length == 0) {
                this.tempt = this.senatorF.filter(j => this.selectarr.includes(j.state));
                return this.searchData(this.tempt)
            } else {
                let  memFilter= [];
                for (let j = 0; j < this.senatorF.length; j++) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < this.checkarr.length; i++) {
                        if (this.senatorF[j].party == this.checkarr[i] && this.senatorF[j].state == this.selectarr) {
                            memFilter.push(this.senatorF[j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return this.searchData(memFilter);
            }
        },
    },
    methods: {
        getStates: function () {
            console.log(this.senatorF)
            this.senatorF.forEach(mem => {
                if (!this.statearr.includes(mem.state)) {
                    this.statearr.push(mem.state);
                    console.log('addrow')
                }
            });
        },
        searchData: function(array){
            return array.filter(mem => mem.fullname.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchName.toLowerCase()) || mem.votes_with_party_pct.toString().includes(this.searchName.toLowerCase()))
        }
    },
};
```

And here is the result in console:
[console result show the function in component run before the fetching data in App.vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peq49.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help section in how to post a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It would greatly increase your chance of getting a relevant answer.

Comment: please provide the code of your store vuex

Comment: I just add code from store vuex in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've made some good progress. Next steps are to follow the proper flow in Vuex for "updating" your store. In your `App.vue` you have your `getData()` method that ultimately does a `fetch()` and you attempt to set your store data using `this.$store.state.senator = this.senatorA`. This is not correct. You should follow Vuex's one way data flow structure.

[image: Vuex One Way Data Flow]

You are attempting to directly change the state without first committing your changes to a mutation, which then directly affects the state. I know this may seem like much, even Evan You (creator of Vue) has said he would like to simplify.

Instead of doing `this.$store.state.senator = this.senatorA`, first you should perform a Vuex dispatch like so, `this.$store.dispatch('storeActionFunction', this.senatorA)`.

Inside of your Vuex Store files, you should have an "Action" (function) that would then call a `commit`. Your commit may look something like `commit('SET_SENATAOR_SOMETHING', data)`. `data` would represent your `this.senatorA` that was passed along via the dispatch.

The `commit()` has 2 params... the Mutation name you are targeting and the data you want to pass along. Then you would have a section in your Vuex store where you specify your Mutations. A mutation titled `'SET_SENATAOR_SOMETHING'` would then take the data passed into it and do something like... `state.senator = data`.

Boom. Done. Seems like a lot, it is, but that's how it works. If you want to see some example files I have a project linked below, but my project is abstracted out to a larger degree than what you're looking to do.

**State**: https://github.com/rebz/vue-meetup-interfaces/blob/master/resources/js/store/modules/people/state.js

**Dispatch**: https://github.com/rebz/vue-meetup-interfaces/blob/master/resources/js/views/people/layouts/layout.vue

**Action**: https://github.com/rebz/vue-meetup-interfaces/blob/master/resources/js/store/modules/people/actions.js

**Mutation**: https://github.com/rebz/vue-meetup-interfaces/blob/master/resources/js/store/modules/people/mutations.js

**Getters**: https://github.com/rebz/vue-meetup-interfaces/blob/master/resources/js/store/modules/people/getters.js

Access Data w/ `{ mapGetters }` (not required): https://github.com/rebz/vue-meetup-interfaces/blob/master/resources/js/views/people/index.vue

Hope this helps!